# Profiling a process via his PID Linux Kernel Programming

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to make a kernel module which monitors the execution time of a process. I can't find the function to get a pointer to the process given the PID (Process ID).

Thanks in advance for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get process descriptor, namely `task_struct` of the process, use `pid_task` to get it from a pid:

```
#include <linux/pid.h>
struct task_struct *pid_task(struct pid *pid, enum pid_type);
```